# Read file in request body with Go Gin

Tags: rest, go, go-gin

I'm getting empty file when I try to read the request body of my HTTP request using Go Gin. On my request I'm sending a file attached to the Request Body (Content Type: application/octet-stream).

```
Request Headers
Authorization: Bearer XXX
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: XXX
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Request Body
src: "Path to my file"
```

Backend Go code:

```
bodySize, _ = strconv.ParseInt(c.Request.Header.Get("Content-Length"), 10, 64)
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, bodySize))
_, err = io.Copy(buf, c.Request.Body)
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

The print sentence prints empty string but the file is not empty (Content Length is 12).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. can you debug the `bodySize` and request's body to ensure it has some value?

Comment: What I can see debugging is that `buf` value is: `[]uint8 len: 0, cap: 12, []` when I initialize it and after the copy changes to: `[]uint8 len: 0, cap: 536, []`  but still empty...

Comment: You need to show a more complete example here. Did you check the errors? What exactly is `[]uint8 len: 0, cap: 536, []` from? What happens if you just use `io.ReadAll`?

Comment: No errors using `io.Copy` (nil), using `n, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)` n is `[]` and no errors neither.

Comment: that's mean the request body contains no data

Comment: is there any middleware that might potentially read the request body?

Comment: What do you mean `n is []`? The `n` value is an integer with the number of bytes copied, not a slice or array. We really need a [mre] to see what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @novalagung yes, I'm reading it in a middleware before the main function, after the middleware the execution continues with `c.Next()` . In the middleware the reading works fine.

Comment: @JimB the length is 0 after the reading.

Comment: If you already read the body, then of course there is no longer anything to read in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @novalagung yes, I'm reading it in a middleware before the main function, after the middleware the execution continues with c.Next() . In the middleware the reading works fine. –

The `http.Request.Body` will be empty after you read its content. You will need to store the request body somewhere after being read, so you do not need to read it twice.

---

Or, there is another alternative workaround, you can put back the content into the `req.Body` after reading it.

```golang
// middleware do read the body
bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
req.Body.Close()  //  must close

// put back the bodyBytes to req.Body
req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
```

**But I do not recommend it!**